# Trying to make a page title notifcation

Tags: javascript

So basically my code checks if an HTML element has the value of not 0, if it doesn't sets a timer to change the page title to a notification type of text.

I'm really, really new to JS, so I don't know why this did not work, I tried getElementById("licon liconspan") aswell, nothing.

EDIT: Okay, so I got this to work how I want it, here's the code:

```js
function changeTitle() {
  var title = document.title;
  var variable = document.querySelector('.liconspan').innerHTML;
  if ((variable) !== 0) {
    setTimeout(changeTitle, 3000);
    document.title = 'You have ' + variable + ' unread messages!';
  }
}
changeTitle();
```

Question though, how can I make it switch back and forth with a title, for example "You got a message" for three seconds then "Page Title" for another three seconds then "You got a message" again, etc..

Comment: span.licon liconspan isn't a valid id. You aren't allowed spaces in them.

Comment: Changed it, still the same, nothing happens

Comment: Show us your full code, with the change.

Comment: See also https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ & http://sscce.org/

Comment: Would it be possible to add the HTML code?  Are you sure "licon liconspan" is an id and not two classes?

Comment: I edited the topic with the new code, it's not showing </script> though

Comment: can you make a fiddle at http://www.jsfiddle.net? please..

Comment: It's a class.. licon liconspan is a class

Comment: @Aboud well then getElementbyId is not going to work on a class! does the element have an id?

Comment: It doesn't actually, this is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/awdtzqga/

Comment: There's no HTML. Without the HTML it's hard to help.

Comment: second that @max add some code Aboud

Comment: HTML code is inside MyBB, I'm using MyBB, let me figure out where the actual code exists

Comment: Open your website, press F12 and then copy & paste the code.

Comment: or just right click and view source and copy and paste that way

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/awdtzqga/ Here you go, best I could do

Comment: thats exactly the same - you have to update it after you paste the code in

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help guys, I learned a thing or two!

Comment: Any idea how can I make it changing titles between one and another, like "You got a message" > "Page Title" > "You got a message"

Comment: updated, can anyone help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery you can get the element by class using a proper selector and check its value, to change the document title you don't need jQuery.

Alternatively you can use [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName):

> The Element.getElementsByClassName() method returns a live
>   HTMLCollection containing all child elements which have all of the
>   given class names. When called on the document object, the complete
>   document is searched, including the root node.

Code:

```
function changeTitle() {
    var title = document.title; 
    if (parseInt($('.liconspan').val()) !== 0 ) {
        setTimeout(changeTitle, 3000);  
        document.title='>'+title;
    }
}
changeTitle();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/c9p670ra/

Comment: Any idea how can I make it changing titles between one and another, like "You got a message" > "Page Title" > "You got a message"

Comment: Ehm may I know why -1?

Comment: So it's better to notice while using another browser tab

Comment: @Aboud I'm sorry but I don't understand the second question...and why is not the accepted answer anymore?